# iPhone SDK building an Omnigraffle like app

Tags: ios4, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, ios5

I have been trying to find an example or some hints on how to create an app that I could drag, resize, rotate images onto a UIView and then save the individual pieces (including their size, rotation and placement) and the entire UIView into CoreData. Kind of like the omnigraffle app.

Any tutorials, examples or anything on any piece of the app would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for dragging a view 
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tkdragview

for roting a view http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ktonefingerrotationgesturerecognizer

for resizing a view 
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/spuserresizableview

What respects to core data, its actually pretty straightforward just, gather the classes in one view, see the properties you need to save, and the new one you will need for your app and thats it.

Like:
Object Canvas containing a many relationship to morphlingViews wich contain all the properties as center, color, width, height, angle, UIPath (if you plan to create custom shapes) layer position (so it gets drawn correctly) and if you plan to connect the views as omnigraffle add a many realtionship to self (in morphlingViews) so you can take the center of different morphlingViews and add a simple line between them. (and a string if you plan to add drawInRect method to allow users to write in the objects, then it will be a good idea to add the text properties as well).

You can also add Quartz Composer drawing styles properties to the object, as shadow, shadowColor, shadowOffset, or add patterColor to add resizable background.